# Using jQuery to set the selected value of a select list based on a name containing an & symbol

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dropdown list that contains a collection of vendor names and their ids. I'm trying to set the selected value of the dropdown list based on the name of the vendor in my model.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#vendors option:contains(@Model.Vendor)  // @Model.Vendor = "A B & C"
            .attr('selected', 'selected');

    });
</script>

@Html.DropDownList("vendors",
    new SelectList(Model.Vendors, "VendorID", "Name"),
    "- Select a Vendor -")
```

For some reason the dropdown list item doesn't get selected if the name contains an ampersand. But if it doesn't, then the list item gets selected.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps try using `:contains(&amp;Words)` instead of `:contains(&Words)`

Comment: @steven Oh wow, I guess you've been working on this for a while...didn't remember that I had already answered a question from you haha. Good to see you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters like `&` get encoded when they appear in HTML (e.g. `&` becomes `&amp;`). To compare your text to the actual text value of the element, you can use something like this:

```
$("#vendors option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf(@Model.Vendor) > -1; // @Model.Vendor = "A B & C"
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Also, for setting an option as 'selected', the correct method to use is [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) (in every version of jQuery 1.6+).